# How do I replace an image URL with an image tag in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string

This is the JSON response I'm getting from the server:

```
 const response = {
   status: "OK",
   data: {
     qr_code_string: "/ AFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAB",
     image_url: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg",
     qr_code: "serse",
     expiry_time: "05-16-2019 10:05:34"
   }
 };
```

I need to display this JSON response in a formatted way which I achieve like this:

```
JSON.stringify(response, null, 4)
```

Now the requirement is to render the `image_url` in an image tag and display rest in JSON.

I was wondering if I could achieve this using a regular expression.

Edit: I'd like to also mention that regardless of the response structure, it could be an array of objects or a nested object. Either by identifying an image url through regex or by identifying the value of the key `image_url`, I'd like to achieve this.

Comment: Is the key `image_url` fixed or can it be anything?

Comment: `data.image_url` or `data['image_url']` ?

Comment: It would be fixed. But I am hoping for a general solution which would detect image urls and convert them to regex. If not, I can work with a solution that assumes `image_url` is fixed @GauravPunjabi

Comment: And the problem is? Just assign `response.data.image_url` as the `src` of an `<img />`

Comment: I would like to display the whole repsponse in a json format with formatted spaces.. except the `image_url`. The response could be an array of object, nested object.. Regardless,I'd like to display the response in a json format and the `image_url` value in a image tag @Andreas

Comment: Assign the url to an `<img />`/`new Image()`, `delete` the property and only then "print" the object with `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @CKA `response` is already in JSON format, what exactly do you mean `formatted spaces`?

Comment: @Andreas As I have said before, I am not sure if the `image_url` would be available inside a loop or a nested object.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I mean rendering the JSON response with formatting in an html div tag

Answer (score 1):

Assign the `image_url` to an `<img />`/`new Image()` element.
Remove the property from the object.
"Print" the object with `JSON.stringify()`

Wrap the logic in a function. Makes it easier to use when the response is an array of objects

```js
const response = {
        status: "OK",
        data: {
            qr_code_string: "/ AFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAB",
            image_url: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg",
            qr_code: "serse",
            expiry_time: "05-16-2019 10:05:34"
        }
    };
    
showResponseObject(response);
// or in case of an array of objects
// response.forEach(showResponseObject);

    
function showResponseObject(res) {
  // the <ul> is just an example

  const list = document.querySelector("ul"),
        li = document.createElement("li"),
        pre = document.createElement("pre"),
        img = new Image();
        
  img.src = res.data.image_url;
  delete res.data.image_url;
  
  pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 4);
  
  li.appendChild(pre);
  li.appendChild(img);
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: As I have commented, regardless of the response structure, I'd like to do this. That is if my response was an array of objects containing the `image_url` as a property along with many other properties, I wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: _"if my response was an array of objects"_ - The solution also works with an array of objects. You either have to adjust the call (see my comment) or wrap the response in an array if it is only one element. Regardless of this the response should always have the same structure: an array of objects (with 1 or many elements)

Comment: What i mean is I do not know the response structure. It could be anything. What i do know is that image_url must be wrapped in an image tag!

Comment: No need to be passive agressive. Thanks for your patience and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new property in `response.data` called `image_html`, this means you don't have to change (or remove) the `image_url` property, **I.E:** you can use it again later on.

```js
const response = {
  status: "OK",
  data: {
    qr_code_string: "/ AFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAB",
    image_url: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg",
    qr_code: "serse",
    expiry_time: "05-16-2019 10:05:34"
  }
};
// more code...
response.data.image_html = `<img src="${ response.data.image_url }" />`;
// even more code...
console.log(response);
```

Output:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "data": {
    "qr_code_string": "/ AFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAB",
    "image_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg",
    "qr_code": "serse",
    "expiry_time": "05-16-2019 10:05:34",
    "image_html": "<img src=\"http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg\" />"
  }
}
```

Here is a sample HTML container:

```
<figure class="container">
  <section id="image"></section>
  <section id="json"></section>
</figure>
```

Then you could display it using:

```
document.querySelector(".container > #image").appendChild(response.data.image_html);
document.querySelector(".container > #json").textContent = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It can be replaced in the [`JSON.stringify` replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) :

```js
const response = {
  status: "OK",
  data: {
    qr_code_string: "/ AFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAB",
    image_url: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/filepicker%2FvCleswcKTpuRXKptjOPo_kitten.jpg",
    qr_code: "serse",
    expiry_time: "05-16-2019 10:05:34"
  }
};

a.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response, (k, v) => k == 'image_url' ? `<img src='${v}' />` : v, 4);
```

```html
<pre id=a />
```